# Why this division algorithm works?

Tags: algorithms

I found this problem on an algorithmic book. I have solve the requestments about time (O(n^2)) but I can't figure out how it works.

Input: Two n-bit integers x and y, where y ≥ 1

Output: The quotient and remainder of x divided by y

```
function divide(x, y)

    if x = 0:
        return (q, r) = (0, 0)

    (q, r) = divide(floor(x/2), y)

    q = 2 · q
    r = 2 · r

    if x is odd:
        r = r + 1

    if r ≥ y:
        r = r − y
        q = q + 1

    return (q, r)
```

Comment: `time (` $O(n^2)$ `)` can you find/argue a tighter bound?

Comment: I think there is not a tighter bound.

Comment: What would this algorithm look like using ten instead of two? Can you make the connection to "schoolbook division"?

Answer (score 1):

For even $a$ and $b \ne 0$ and integral division
$$ \frac{a}{b} = \frac{2a}{2b} = 2 \cdot \frac{( a / 2 )}{b} $$
Similarly for the remainder
$$a = 2 \cdot \frac{a}{2} \space (mod \space b)$$
Effectively transforming your problem of division of number with `n` bits into division of a number with `n-1` bits (half as big number).

The algorithm uses integral division in the `floor(x\2)` part and there you might lose `1` if `x` was odd. You're giving it back with the `if x is odd:` block to the remainder and since this might make your reminder the same size as `y` you need to check if that happened and change the values accordingly. (Notice that `r > y` can never happen and there could be just as fine `if r == y:`.)

You just do this `n` times where `n` is the number of bits of `x`.

Finally the algorithm is not $O(n^2)$ but rather $O(n)$ in the number of bits of `x`. That's assuming the `floor(x/2)` part does **not** call the `divide` function, because that would end in infinite loop (you would need e.g. compute `a/2` to compute `a/b` which would in turn need again computation of `a/2`. This can be avoided by using `a>>1` instead of `a/2` which also authomatically floors the result).